# Using the Ext.NET library in an ASP.NET Monodevelop project

Tags: asp.net, monodevelop, ext.net

I would like to use the *wonderful* Ext.NET library (.dll) inside a MonoDevelop project.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I register it in my project to see the `<ext:something>`  extension like the `<asp:textbox>` for standard asp.net controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much personal experience with Ext.NET + Mono, but I do know several community members have been successfully developing with Mono. The following search results may help track down a bit more information, see

http://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Aforums.ext.net+mono